# Vertical alignment with - sign in the middle of the page

Tags: align, vertical-alignment

I am working on my titlepage for a report and I have a list of supervisors. I want this to be aligned so that the - sign is in the middle of the page (so right below "By"). As you can see it is now shifted to the right.

I am now using the align environment (I also tried tabular but that did not work out):

```
\emph{By:}\\[0.4cm]

\quad Some person namely me\\[1.5cm]% Author info

\large

\emph{Supervisors:}
\begin{align*}
\text{This is quite a long name}& - \text{Some university}\\
\text{Short name}& - \text{Some university}\\
\text{Short name}& - \text{Small}\\
\text{Also long name}& - \text{Small}\\[1.5cm]
\end{align*}
```

I think this can be easily adjusted, I just do not know how :)

[image]

Comment: This is really about horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 1):

One possible (easy) approach it is to use a `tabular` environment.

[image: c]

This is the code.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{center}
        \large
        \begin{tabular}{r@{}c@{}l}  
            & \textit{By:}  &           \\[0.4cm]
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{\hspace*{5em} Some person namely me} \\[1.5cm]% Author info
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{\hspace*{5em}\textit{Supervisors:}}               \\[0.4cm]
            This is quite a long name   & --            &Some university\\
            Short name                  & --            &Some university\\
            Short name                  & --            &Small      \\
            Also long name              & --            &Small      \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}  
        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make boxes of the appropriate width. At the end, of course, remove the `\smash{...}` part that's used to show the alignment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\supervisor}[2]{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-1em][r]{#1}%
  \makebox[2em]{---}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-1em][l]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

Some University

\vfill

Title of the thesis

\vfill

\textit{By:}

\vspace{1ex}

I Myself

\vspace{8ex}

\textit{Supervisors:}

\vspace{1ex}

\supervisor{This is quite a long name}{Some university}\\
\supervisor{Short name}{Some university}\\
\supervisor{Short name}{Small}\\
\supervisor{Also long name}{Small}

\vfill

20\smash{\kern-0.05pt\vrule height \textheight width 0.1pt \kern-0.05pt}22

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With new package `tabularray` it is easy to set:

- right alignment in a `X` column (`X[r]`)
- the separator you like instead of vertical rules, `vline{2} = {-}{text={--}}` means that the second vertical line (`vline{2}`) of any columns (`{-}`) should be `--` (`{text={--}}`).

Since your MWE is not complete, I chose the `report` documentclass.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\emph{By:}
\vspace{0.4cm}

Some person namely me\vspace{1.5cm}

\large

\emph{Supervisors:}\vspace{.5cm}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[r]X}, 
    vline{2} = {-}{text={--}}
    }
This is quite a long name & Some university\\
Short name & Some university\\
Short name & Small\\
Also long name & Small\\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]